# MSSQL - Masking data based on mapping table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace, masking

wanted to perform data masking according to mapping as below by using MSSQL 2008R2:

---

**Mapping Table**

```
A = C
B = A
C = E
1 = 3
2 = 1
3 = 9
```

**Original**

```
ABC123
```

**Masked**

```
CAE319
```

---

The idea would be using replace however the second replace function will replacing previous replaced value.

```
select Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(REPLACE('ABC123', 'A', 'C'), 'B', 'A'), 'C', 'E'), '1', '3'), '2', '1'), '3', '9')
```

Result: **CAE319**

P.s. value edited, because Reverse or reverse replace cannot be use in this case

any idea?

Comment: Yes, don't use replace, use split, join and group concat (for xml path and stuff).

Comment: You need to change the order of the replaces.  From in to out, do 3-2-1-C-B-A.

Comment: @sphenix change your replace order. Your current order is not transitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a more table approach.

There are two code segments below which will Mask or UnMask a string.  Easily converted into a UDF or even placed in a CROSS APPLY

```
Declare @Mask table (MapFrom varchar(10),MapTo varchar(10))
Insert into @Mask values 
('A','C'),
('B','D'),
('C','E'),
('1','2'),
('2','3'),
('3','9')


Declare @Yourtable table (ID int,SomeCol varchar(max))
Insert Into @Yourtable values
(1,'ABC123')

-- To Mask
Declare @U varchar(max) ='ABC123'

Select NewSting = Stuff((Select ''+S 
    From (
        Select N
                ,S=IsNull(MapTo,Substring(@U,N,1))
            From (Select Top (Len(@U)) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null)) From master..spt_values)  N
            Left Join @Mask on Substring(@U,N,1)=MapFrom
        ) X 
    Order By N
    For XML Path ('')),1,0,'') 

-- To UnMask
Declare @M varchar(max) = 'CDE239'

Select NewSting = Stuff((Select ''+S 
    From (
        Select N
                ,S=IsNull(MapFrom,Substring(@M,N,1))
            From (Select Top (Len(@M)) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null)) From master..spt_values)  N
            Left Join @Mask on Substring(@M,N,1)=MapTo
        ) X 
    Order By N
    For XML Path ('')),1,0,'')
```

Comment: I was too lazy to write a full answer :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled Copy and Paste my friend... copy and paste  :)

Comment: wow, I was tend to ask how could you brain so fast with this solution.......it works man.....thanks thanks....

Comment: @sphenix Happy it helped

Comment: just wonder is it possible to avoid use "master..spt_values" ? because I'm afraid no authority to use that

Comment: @sphenix Sure, any table will do.  Just has to have a respectable number of rows (more than the max length of your string)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the order of replace and reverse the result

```
select REVERSE( Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(REPLACE('321CBA', '3', '9'), '2', '3'), '1', '2'), 'C', 'E'), 'B', 'D'), 'A', 'C'))
```

**RESULT :**

```
CDE239
```

EDIT:

```
Declare @Mask table (MapFrom varchar(10),MapTo varchar(10))
Insert into @Mask values 
('A','C'),
('B','A'),
('C','E'),
('1','3'),
('2','1'),
('3','9')

DECLARE @pos INT
    ,@result VARCHAR(100)
    ,@maskfrom NCHAR(1)
    ,@mask_to NCHAR(1);

SET @result = 'ABC123';
SET @pos = 1

WHILE @pos < LEN(@result) + 1
BEGIN
    SELECT @mask_to = MapTo
    FROM @mask
    WHERE MapFrom = substring(@result, @pos, 1)

    SET @result = STUFF(@result, @pos, 1, @mask_to);
    SET @pos = @pos + 1;
END

SELECT @result
```

**RESULT**

CAE319

Comment: it may work in this case, but the mapping table actually can be maintain by users, reverse may not be good idea.

Comment: this might worked too.....however if the value not fall into the mapping table, it will become 9. But hey, I've learned something from you guys, thanks @shiju